# const of generic Float type and declaration

Tags: generics, rust, constants

I am trying to implement a constant value of generic type, but the compiler can't figure out the type (Error: cannot find type `T` in this scope).

```
use num::Float

pub const R: T = T::from(8314.4621).unwrap();

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", foo(3.0_f64))
}

pub fn foo<T: Float>(a: T) -> T {
    a * R
}
```

- How should I declare the implemented traits for `T` like the `Float` trait of the `num` crate?
- Furthermore, is there any easier way to declare the value instead of this verbose way `T::from(8314.4621).unwrap()`?
- Just to be sure, is this solved in compile or run time?

Comment: Thks @PitaJ, I have tried to extend the question with the general idea.

Comment: `num::Float` methods are not `const`, so they can't be used in a `const` context.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way for the compiler to be able to split the constant among the different types. And if I use inside `foo` `a * T::from(R).unwrap()` would the transformation be performed in compile or in run time?

Comment: You definitely can't have a generic constant at top-level like this. "const generics" means that you can use constants as generic parameters, not that you can have generic constants.

Comment: @SergioCavaleiroCosta if "R" is known at compile time (propagated from const values/literals), then the compiler will likely be able to compute the result of multiplication at compile time and just insert the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a generic `const`. You have to perform the calculation inside `foo()`:

```rust
pub fn foo<T: Float>(a: T) -> T {
    a * T::from(8314.4621).unwrap()
}
```

> - Furthermore, is there any easier way to declare the value instead of this verbose way `T::from(8314.4621).unwrap()`?

Not for arbitrary numbers (for special numbers, e.g. `0`, `-0`, `1`, ∞, etc. you can use the methods of the `Float` trait and supertraits, e.g. [`zero()`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.Zero.html#tymethod.zero)).

> - Just to be sure, is this solved in compile or run time?

For `const` (which you can't), at compile time.

If inlined, at runtime, but the compiler will optimize it away.